# How to update src attribute of the video element with mouse clicks?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've this simple app that has a list of videos of the side menu and a player on the right side of it. For some reason, I've made separate components for the list and the video player. What I want is, when a user clicks on any item of the list, the corresponding video should load/play in the player. But I'm not able to update the `src` of the `video` element.

Here's my code:

main-content.component.html

```
...
<mat-list *ngFor="let video of videos;let i = index">
  <button (click)="setloadVid(video)" type="button">{{video.title}}</button>
</mat-list>
...
//Selector for playing video
<app-play-video></app-play-video>
...
```

main.component.ts

```
videos;
obs = new Subject<string>();
obs$ = this.obs.asObservable();

constructor(private vid: VideosService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.videos = this.vid.VIDEOS;
  //this is just to make sure that that the first video loads when the page loads.
  this.obs.next("../../assets/secure-content/vid1.mp4");
}

setloadVid(video: any) {
  this.obs.next(video.src);
}
```

My player component:

play-video.component.html

```
<div class="video-container video">
  <video width="400px" height="300px" controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer>
    <source [src]="src$ | async" type="video/mp4" /> Browser not supported
  </video>
</div>
```

play-video.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-play-video',

...

src$: Observable<string>;

constructor(private mainContPg: MainContentComponent) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.src$ = this.mainContPg.obs$;
}
```

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: You can pass the src through data binding in play-video and on ngOnChage you will get the new src.

Comment: Add the `Subject` in your servcie not in your component, use serivice to pass data from one component to another..

Comment: @SujataChanda, thank you for your response. I tried your solution.(It is even the first answer of the question), but it's not working. In the ngOnChanges method, I can update the src, but it is not reflected in the template. If you have any alternate solution to this, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: @AshishRanjan, I was doing the same way, but I made many changes to make the code functional and ended up injecting MainContentComponent into PlayVideoComponent. But thank you for your remark!

Comment: Solved this by using `src` attribute inside the `video` element. `<video [src]="src" ..>...</video>`

Answer (score 1):

Set an input to your second component

```
<button (click)="currentVideo = video" type="button">{{video.title}}</button>
...
<app-play-video [video]="currentVideo"></app-play-video>
```

Declare it in your component

```
videos;
currentVideo;
```

In your second component, declare it too

```
@Input() video;
```

Implement the `OnChanges` interface to change the source of the video

```
export class PlayVideoComponent implement onChanges {
  ...
  src;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.src = this.video.src;
  }
  ...
}
```

And remove the async part of your HTML

```
<source [src]="src" type="video/mp4" /> Browser not supported
```

Comment: `<source [src]="video?.src" type="video/mp4" />`??

Comment: @AshishRanjan I made the least changes I could do. Removing a $ is less than `video?.src`.

Comment: @trichetriche, thank you for your response. But this is not working. The video still looks broken and I get this error in the console: GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found) I'm not navigating anywhere in the components. Also, the src is updated in the play-video.component.ts file but is not reflected in the template.

Comment: @A.Ranjan yeah that's not because of that code, that's because of you : your source does not exist (error 404). Give it a valid source and see how it behaves.

Comment: @A.Ranjan I don't care about your repository ... Simply find the right link to the source and tell me if you have any more error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with async that is getting called in the template which will execute only once. Instead handle it inside my player component. Also use BehaviorSubject and set the first video as default.

videos;

```
obs = new BehaviorSubject<string>('../../assets/secure-content/vid1.mp4');
obs$ = this.obs.asObservable();
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-play-video',

...

src$: Observable<string>;

constructor(private mainContPg: MainContentComponent) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.mainContPg.obs$.subscribe((vsrc)=>{
    this.src = vsrc;
  });
}
```